# Not able to load and scrape data from webpage using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from https://www.grailed.com/ using the Scrapy framework in Python, but when I'm in the

```
scrapy shell
```

and trying to learn how to extract the data, with

```
response.css("my css path")
```

or

```
response.xpath("my xpath")
```

I always get empty lists. Then, when I fetch and view the response in the shell for https://www.grailed.com, I get an almost blank page that does not contain the data that I would like to scrape (items, price, etc). In this case, would Scrapy still work for my purposes? If not, are there any alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to use `Regex` for scraping data? Do you wish to have a comprehensive answer explaining it?

Comment: I managed to solve my problem by using Selenium to open a headless instance of the webpage that loaded all the JS and then scraped the data from there. But I would also like to learn about how to use Regex for scraping data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site loads content using JS. Scrapy does not support JS. That is why you see empty html template without data itself.
Possible solutions:

1. Try using headless browser that will execute all JS on the page. At times I find phantomjscloud very handy API solution for rendering JS sites. You can use like this - [enter link description here](https://phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request=%7Burl:%22https://www.grailed.com%22,renderType:%22HTML%22%7D)
2. Check network conenctions tab to see if there are some API calls that return data you need in json format, so you can get it directly.[image: Like this one]

Comment: Would there be anyway to get the data that is already in JSON format without manually going to Chrome developer?

Comment: Yes. You can mimic post request and send it using scrapy or python requests. It will return Json object.